# How to get the color used for a specific blackberry calendar

Tags: blackberry, colors, calendar

On the BlackBerry there are different colors for each calendar. I know how you can get the names of all the calendars, but is there a way to get the color it uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such API available for that.